# C function change string using pointer

Tags: c, string, function

I'm trying to make a function that changes a char array from the main function, that's what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void change(char *a);

int main()
{
    char a[] = "hello";
    printf("\na = %s", a);
    change(a);
    printf("%\na = %s", a);
    getch();
}

void change(char *a)
{
    a = "goodbye";
}
```

Comment: In `main`, `a` is an array. All you can do is modify its contents. You certainly can't fit an array of length 8 into it since it only has room for 6.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: You need to decide whether you want to modify an array, or modify a pointer to an array

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several problems with this code, but first we need to take a step back and talk about how arrays are handled in C.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

In the declaration

```
char a[] = "hello";
```

`"hello"` is a string literal, which has type "6-element array of `char`" (5 characters plus the 0 terminator).  Since it is being used to initialize the array `a` in a declaration, the rule above doesn't apply; instead, the size of `a` is set to be the same as the size of the literal (6), and the contents of the string literal are copied to the array.

When you call `change` from `main` as

```
change(a);
```

the *expression* `a` has type "6-element array of `char`".  Since it is neither a string literal nor the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, that expression will be converted to type "pointer to `char`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the aray.  Hence why the `change` function is declared as

```
void change(char *a);
```

In this context, `a` is simply a pointer.  When you write

```
a = "goodbye";
```

the string literal `"goodbye"` is not being used in an initializer, and it's not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, so the expression is converted to type "pointer to `char`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first character.  So what happens here is that you're copying the *address* of the string literal `"goodbye"` to `a`.  This overwrites the value in `a`, but this `a` is not the same object in memory as the *array* `a` in `main`, so any changes to it are not reflected in `main`.

If you want to update the *contents* of an array, you will need to use the library functions `strcpy/strncpy` (for 0-terminated strings) or `memcpy` (for everything else), or update each element explicitly (`a[0]='g'; a[1]='o'; a[2]='o';`, etc).

To update the contents of `a`, you'd use

```
strcpy( a, "goodbye" );
```

**Except**...

`a` is only large enough to hold 5 characters plus a 0 terminator; `"goodbye"` is 7 characters plus the 0 terminator; it's two characters larger than what `a` is capable of storing.  C will happliy let you perform the operation and trash the bytes immediately following `a`, which may lead to any number of problems (buffer overruns such as this are a classic malware exploit).  You have a couple of choices at this juncture:

First, you could declare `a` to be large enough to handle either string:

```
#define MAX_LEN 10
...
char a[MAX_LEN] = "hello";
```

Second, you could limit the size of the string copied to `a`:

```
void change( char *a, size_t size )
{
  strncpy( a, "goodbye", size - 1 );
  a[size - 1] = 0;
}
```

Note that you will need to pass the number of elements `a` can store as a separate parameter when you call `change`; there's no way to tell from a pointer how big the array it points to is:

```
change( a, sizeof a / sizeof *a ); // although in this case, sizeof a would be
                                   // sufficient.
```

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you are sending a copy of the char pointer a by doing this:

```
void change(char *a)
{
    a = "goodbye";
}
```

if you want to change a value in another function you should do this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void change(char **a);

int main()
{
    char *a = "hello";
    printf("\na = %s", a);
    change(&a);
    printf("%\na = %s", a);
    getch();
}

void change(char **a)
{
    *a = "goodbye";
}
```

Comment: Your "change" function doesn't match the function prototype.

Comment: That seems to work.  I am not clear why char a[] had to be changed to char* though.

Answer (score -2):

I changed the function, now it works, this way:

```
void change(char *a)
{
    strcpy(a, "goodbye");
}
```

Comment: David is watching you :)

Comment: Remember: Works != Good