# How can I change the value of a char using a pointer?

Tags: c, function, pointers, pass-by-reference, c-strings

So I am quite new to using pointers and wanted to know how I could do the following but for a string value.

```
int number(int, int *);
int main()
{
    int a = 15;
    int b =0;
    
    number(a,&b);
    
    fprintf(stdout,"Number b is %d\n",b);
    return 0;
}


int number(int a, int *b) {
    
    *b = a;
     
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C function change string using pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668796/c-function-change-string-using-pointer)

Comment: Thanks I will have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you mean something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * assign( char **s1, char *s2 )
{
    return *s1 = s2;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s1 = "Hello World!";
    char *s2;
    
    puts( assign( &s2, s1 ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World!
```

That is to assign a value to the pointer `s2` (that has the type `char *`)  within the function you need to pass it to the function by reference as you are doing in your program with an object of the type `int`. Otherwise the function will deal with a copy of its argument and changes the copy will not influence on the argument.

Passing an object by reference in C means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it.

If you have character arrays that store strings then to copy a string to a character array you can use the standard string function `strcpy` declared in the header `<string.h>`.